# RTL SDR "dark region"

Tags: software-defined-radio, hf, rtl-sdr

I'm new to RTL SDR, and I noticed there's a "dark region" (around 700-900MHz), and I haven't figured out why this is.

My device's tuner is a Fitipower FC0012, where could I find the pinout and dataspecs for this tuner?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the site, Andrew! We edited your question to make it clearer. I noticed that you're asking two distinctly different questions. Please ask the pinout question in a new question. You're also more likely to get an answer when you do.

Comment: Also, have you Googled *Fitipower FC0012 pinout*? If you find that, there's no need to ask a separate question.

Comment: Yes I have, unfortunately I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

700-900MHz is "blocked" by law in the US and a number of other countries due to a (now antiquated) law that was designed to prevent wideband communications receivers from eaves dropping on old analog cellphones, which broadcast in the clear.

These days it's entirely unnecessary, but it's still on the books because regulators are lazy like that.

As for removing the limitation, I couldn't say, not being terribly familiar with the current SDR software offerings. In the case of these RTL-SDR dongles, it seems virtually certain the block is being applied in software, not hardware.

Comment: Knowing the guys currently maintaining the open source librtlsdr driver, I'd be a bit surprised if this was actually enforced by software.